# Showing $\overline{N(A,\epsilon)}=\{x\in\mathbb R^n \ | \ \rho(x,A)\leq\epsilon\}$

Tags: general-topology

For nonempty $A\subset\mathbb R^n$and a point $x\in\mathbb R^n$, the distance is defined as below.
$$\rho(x,A)=\inf\{\|x-y\| \ | \ y\in A\}$$

And in this question, a cover contains $A$ is defined as below.
$${N(A,\epsilon)}=\{x\in\mathbb R^n \ | \ \rho(x,A)<\epsilon\}$$

I found $N(A,\epsilon)$ is an open set, and next I have to show that its closure has the formula $\{x\in\mathbb R^n \ | \ \rho(x,A)\leq\epsilon\}$.

My approach was to show that each side is in the other side, but I got stucked here : I cannot find that the right side is in the left side.

Could anyone give me some hints? Is there other elegant short proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by right and left side.  Nonetheless, I'm guessing you're having trouble with proving 
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \, \mid \, \rho(x,A) \leq \epsilon\} \subseteq \overline{N(x,\epsilon)}.$$

Try this: if $\rho(x,A) = \epsilon$, then we know that for each $\delta > 0$ there's an $a \in A$ such that $$\|x - a\| < \epsilon + \delta.$$  Now consider the line passing through $x$ and $a$.  Intuitively, if I move along this line just a little, I will be closer to $a$ than $x$ was and, hopefully, I can do this in such a way that, in fact, the distance to $a$ is less than $\epsilon$.

Try this: move a distance $2 \delta$ along the line away from $x$ and toward $a$.  Call this point $y$.  How close is $y$ to $a$?  How close is $y$ to $x$?  (This trick is happening in $1$ dimension so we can draw it and treat everything like we're on a ruler, at least to start with.) By the way, at most how far is $y$ from $A$?  (i.e. do we have an upper bound on $\rho(y,A)$?)

Now, this construction works for every $\delta > 0$ so if you have the right answers to the previous three questions and you're happy with the definition of closure we should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So you means : If consider the line joining two points($x$ and $a$) and an arbitrary $2\delta$-ball of $x$, the intersection  would have a point $y$ which might be in $N(A,\epsilon)$. So $x$ will be in the closure. Understand it.\\
Sorry for asking again, but could this argument be applied to general metric(or normed vector) space? I think a "line" may not be well-defied..

Comment: A line remains well-defined in a normed vector space: it's just the set $\{\lambda x +(1- \lambda)a \, \mid \, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$.  (You could use $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ if the vector space is complex.)  The proof still works in that case.  I believe connectedness is required if you want your statement to be true in a general metric space.